# Meaning of symbols in the Debug area from Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

What do the symbols that are at the left in the Debug Area from the XCode mean? i, A, L, E, etc...

[image: snapshot from Debug Area]

I was looking for that information in the Apple docs ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-debug_navigator/articles/about_debug_navigator.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/about_debug_area.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009986-CH3-SW1), basicly), but could not find it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I could only find a list of the variable types from Ken Orr's "Debugging with Xcode" WWDC 2012 [presentation slides](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_412__debugging_in_xcode.pdf) (Session 412). You may, or may not, have access to these slides.

- L: Local Variable
- A: Argument
- S: Static Variable
- V: Global Variable (Darker)
- R: Register
- V: Instance Variable (Lighter)
- E: Expression

Note: I cannot be more specific about the different colours of the 'V' variables as I am colour-blind. Boo hoo, poor me. Perhaps you can tell me?

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I can´t access the file and I think the list is not complete (in my debugger I see also an "i", maybe they change it and the "V" that referes to an "Instance variable" is now an "i"...), but but still the list is helpful. :)

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban Cool.  And the colours?  Care to enlighten me as to what the two 'V' ones are?

Comment: L, V and V are green
A and E are kinda of purple
S and R are pink-red.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban So both 'V's are green, just lighter and darker?

Comment: To me, both look the same... 
Maybe the "Instance Variable" a little bit lighter. Man, I´m going to start thinking that I´m color blind too...

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban Yeah I think you are mate; I can at least see they are different shades...

Answer (score 4):

Apple developers must have added it to the docs after this question was asked, as it is in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

There are actually only 6 labels, `L, A, S, V, R, E,` where `V` is shared between Global and instance variables. At least now, they are exactly the same colour.

[image: Screenshot of label names].